# Must it be a many-to-many relationship when two foreign keys occur?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

This question maybe be silly, but I just want to confirm whether I get the basic understanding correctly, so:

**Must** it be a `many to many relationship` when **two foreign keys** occur in a table?

Or are there any other terms/reasons when **two foreign keys** are in a table?

Comment: Suppose you've got a table `OrderLine`, with fields `Order`, `Article` and `Amount`. Two possible foreign keys, but this is not what most people consider a many-to-many relationship. It's two separate many-to-one relationships. I'm not sure if this is what you meant to ask.

Comment: yes it is the case I am facing and I try understand whether it is mm relationship or not. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**

Counter-example:

```
create table eg1 (
  id int primary key,
  id1 int,
  id2 int,
  foreign key (id1) references othertable.id,
  foreign key (id2) references sometable.id,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id1_UNIQUE` (`id1` ASC)
);
```

This is not a many-to-many relationship because `id1` is unique.  It has two foreign keys, but is expressing a 1:n and a 1:1 relationship to the two other tables.

Comment: Thanks for this, Matt. Is it necessary to have the auto increment primary key in this kind of table such as your example above?

Comment: Having an auto-increment has nothing to do with whether there's a 1:n, 1:1, or m:n relationship.

Comment: OK. thanks. I thought it could be useful at some point... so I guess it has no use at all.

Comment: Nice. The relationships could even be both `1:1`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that will always be the case. I can think of several situations where there are multiple FKeys in a table. For example:

**tblShirts**
ShirtId int (PKey)
ColorId int (FKey tblColors)
SizeId  int (FKey tblSizes)
StyleId int (FKey tblStyles)
Price money
QtyOnHand int

In this example **tblColors**, **tblSizes** and **tblStyles** are simple lookup tables. There's no need to create a **linking table** to resolve a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @ypercube - How do you figure it is a many-to-many-to-many relationship table? What reference are you using to base you comment on?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, not in the strict sense. The relationships are not identifying, the 3 tables are only reference tables.

Comment: But in a wide sense, this table stores the relationship: *"There is a shirt with this Color, this Size and this Style"*

Comment: I've gotten burned in the past and now I tend to use FKeys even if the data seems trivial as in ColorId above. I've seen cases where it was assumed that ColorId = 1 = Red. Then all sorts of embedded code displays the lteral value "Red" anytime ColorId = 1. Then someone new comes along and says "From now on we want to use Crimson instead of Red". It's much easier to maintain a simple lookup or reference table insted a doing a global find and replace for embedded literals.

Comment: Yes, reference tables are valuable. You can also use them in MySQL to enforce some types of `CHECK` constraints (that MySQL hasn't yet adopted).

Comment: I see your point. I was trying to address the OP's question that if two or more FKeys appear in a table does it mean that's a many-to-many. Not my best example.

Comment: No, it's fine. A ternary relationship is different than a binary one.